# View Fields in custom object layout from another object

Tags: cross-object

I have an object (object1) which have a lookup relationship to the object (object2)
is there any way to view fields from (object1) in the layout of (object2)
thanks

Comment: no, but you can create formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like there can be zero to many `object1` instance referencing an `object2` instance. So you should be able to add `object1` as a related list in the layout of `object2` and display up to 10 fields of each related `object1` object.

(From the `object1` side where only zero or one `object2` instances are related, you can add formula fields to `object1` that reference `object2` fields and so show values in the detail part of `object1`'s layout.)